# ERROR: AWS::Lambda::LayerVersion unzipped size error, with zip asset

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, nestjs, aws-cdk, aws-cdk-typescript

I'm trying to deploy a NestJS application to a lambda function using AWS CDK.

I am using a LambdaLayer to publish the node_modules. By default, it is not possible, because of size limitations, so I'm adding it to a zip file and trying to deploy it with that.

Here is the code:

```js
    const lambdaLayer = new LayerVersion(
      this,
      `${this.env}-${this.deploymentName}-${this.lambdaLayer}`,
      {
        code: Code.fromAsset(resolve(__dirname, "../api/node_modules.zip")),
        compatibleRuntimes: [Runtime.NODEJS_14_X],
        description: "Api Handler Dependencies",
      }
    );

    const handler = new Function(
      this,
      `${this.env}-${this.deploymentName}-${this.lambdaFunction}`,
      {
        functionName: `${this.env}-${this.deploymentName}-${this.lambdaFunction}`,
        code: Code.fromAsset(resolve(__dirname, "../api/dist"), {
          exclude: ["node_modules"],
        }),
        handler: "main.api",
        runtime: Runtime.NODEJS_14_X,
        layers: [lambdaLayer],
        environment: {},
      }
    );
```

In the `api` folder the pipeline executes the following:

```bash
    - rm -rf node_modules
    - npm ci --omit-dev
    - npm run zip:node_modules
```

In the `package.json` I have the following line under scripts: `"zip:node_modules": "zip -r node_modules.zip node_modules"`

So the project (after the API is built), is actually removing the node_modules, installing just the dependencies and I'm trying to zip it. Until that looks good, but when it's time to apply the `Stack`, I'm running into an error:

```
BackendServiceStack | 11:23:54 AM | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::Lambda::LayerVersion   | dev-*****-lambda-layer (*****) Unzipped size must be smaller than 262144000 bytes (Service: AWSLambdaInternal; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValueException; Request ID: ******; Proxy: null)
```

What am I missing, or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe, I know the issue, but not sure yet. I'm using gitlab-ci.yml and I was "caching" all the built stuff. I'm zipping everything into the lambda source, and it works well.

Comment: Any update on this ? I am still getting this error using nest.js